# binding dropdownlist to a dataset returned from a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dataset

I have written the following method that binds the dropdown to the dataset. I need to call this method twice in my project on different pages. So I created a class and put the method in it and I am trying to access this method by creating an object. Having trouble doing so...

```
 public void bind()
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT CountryName + '(+' + CountryCode + ')' As CountryName,CountryCode from ACountry";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds1, "AUser");
        ddlCountryCode.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AUser"];
        ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";

        //ddlCountryCode.SelectedValue = "India(+91)";
        ddlCountryCode.DataBind();
        ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));
        con.Close();
    }
```

If I write this complete method in the new class, it does not recognize the controls (the dropdownlist) used in it & so it throws an error. So I included only the following part in it:

```
  public void bindddl()
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT CountryName + '(+' + CountryCode + ')' As CountryName,CountryCode from ACountry";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds1, "AUser");

        con.Close();
    }
```

now this returns a dataset that I need to bind with the dropdown list on another form (.aspx). How do I do that?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bind objbind = new Bind();
        ddlCountryCode.DataSource = objbind.---->?????????;
        ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";

        //ddlCountryCode.SelectedValue = "India(+91)";
        ddlCountryCode.DataBind();
        ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));
    }
```

Also, What else can I do? Is there another better option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your function returns DataSet then assign it to whatever you want

```
 public DataSet bindddl()
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT CountryName + '(+' + CountryCode + ')' As CountryName,CountryCode from ACountry";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds1, "AUser");

        con.Close();

        return ds1;
    }
```

Then assign them as below.

```
Bind objbind = new Bind();
ddlCountryCode.DataSource = objbind.bindddl().Tables["AUser"];
```

Comment: type or namespace dataset could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference or directive...? --->public Dataset bindddl()

Comment: @AdityaNawandar - did you add using System.Data; at the top of the class ?

Comment: yes... never mind, I retyped "Dataset" and it was done. thanks... (marked as answer)

Comment: I have another problem though.. why is it only taking the code and not the country name from the table??

Comment: because you specify it with that line ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";

Comment: ok I got that. Now I want it to select India by default always. How do I do that? It takes the country codes in alphabetical order so it always has afghanistan(+93) by default. how do I change it to have India by default

Comment: BTW I tried this which dint work...
 ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));
        }

Comment: ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India").Selected = true;

Comment: object reference not set to instance of an object'''

Comment: Im giving a sample of the value 'India', please write what is appropriate for you.

Comment: I tried everything there...
"India","India(+91)","(+91)","91"... nothing working...